# How to create an 64bit rpm package that obsoletes an 32bit package?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I had a 32bit application that I recently ported to 64bit and created a new x86_64 rpm package for it. I would like to have the ability to replace the old i386 package with the new x86_64 package as part as the normal upgrade process on 64bit machines.

However, when I try to upgrade my old i386 package to the x86_64 packages (rpm -Uv MyPackage.version-release.x86_64), the upgrade fails because of file conflicts. If I add the --replacefiles flag to the upgrade command, the upgrade succeeds but when I query the rpm DB (rpm -q MyPackage) I see two installed packages:

MyPackage.version-release.i386

MyPackage.version-release.x86_64

I tried to add the "Obsoletes" tag in the spec file of my x86_64 package, but it seems that a package from one arch cannot obsolete a package from another arch.

I also tried to explicitly remove the i386 package for the x86_64 %postinstall script and it failed because of rpm locking mechanism (can't call rpm from inside rpm...)

Is there any way to do this as part of the package install\upgrade process?

Thanks,
Tzippi.

Comment: Better place to ask this questions is  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You added what `Obsoletes` tag to your spec file exactly? And what happened when you tried installing that package?

Comment: If you just want the upgrade to work you could ship a "dummy" 32bit package as well that version-matched the 64bit package and that *should* let the upgrade work correctly (and leave you with a 32bit package that can then be removed by the user, etc.). Though this does, somewhat, just kick the can down the road.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @EtanReisner - Regarding the Obsoletes tag: Lets say the last 32bit package was with version 1.1-0 and the new 64bit package is with version 1.2-0. I tried to add "Obsoletes: MyPackage < 1.2" and "Obsoletes: MyPackage.1.1-0.i386", but non of them worked. In both cases I got the same result as without the Obsoletes tag - The 32bit package remained on the system even after the 64bit package was installed.

Answer (score 2):

Let say that your last package for i386 has version 1.1. Create this new package:

```
BridgeForMyPackage.spec:
Version: 1
BuildArch: noarch
Obsoletes: MyPackage < 1.2
Provides:  MyPackage = 1.2
Provides:  AnyOtherProvideWhichAreInOriginalPackage
```

This will be kind a bridge for migration, and likely not even installed. Then create:

```
MyPackage.spec:
Version: 1.3
Obsoletes: BridgeForMyPackage < 2
```

So Yum will choose migration from MyPackage-1.1.i386 to BridgeForMyPackage-1.noarch and immediately to MyPackage-1.3.x86_64.

Comment: If this was done in two distinct steps I expect this might work. Are you sure yum calculates this correctly if done in one step?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @msuchy. I tried this, using rpm instead of yum, and it worked partially: I ran the command "rpm -Uv MyPackage.1.3-0.x86_64.rpm BridgeForMyPackage.1-0.noarch.rpm". This resulted in the Bridge package installed first and the removal of the i386 package, and then the x86_64 package was installed successfully, but it didn't remove the Bridge package. Since the bridge package is empty, the only side-effect is having the BridgePackage listed as an installed package, but this is the same result I have with the i386 package... I will try again with yum.

Comment: Try that with yum. I'm pretty sure it works as we done exactly this in Spacewalk project.